# Update service reference error

Tags: c#, silverlight, web-services

I am trying to update the service reference in my silverlight application to a web service that I have just updated to target version 4 framework.

When it was running on version 3.5 and I made any changes, then updated in the client, it working fine however since changing the web service target framework I am getting an error stating that there was an error downloading the web service URL.

How can I update the service reference after changing the framework?

Comment: is the service actually working after you updated the target framework? can you browse the metadata of the service?

Comment: If you remove the web reference from the project and then add it again, does it work?